# Rails 4 link_to larger, static image

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My files are stored in `app/assets/images/subdirectory/image.png` and `app/assets/images/subdirectory/image_full.png`.

In my `app/views/home.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag("subdirectory/image.png"), asset_path("subdirectory/image_full.png")) %>
```

I've also tried:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag("subdirectory/image.png"), asset_path("subdirectory/image_full.png", image)) %>
<%= link_to (image_tag("subdirectory/image.png"), image_path("subdirectory/image.png", image)) %>
```

Couldn't find much via the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

But it totally crashes my app when I attempt to load the view!

## ANSWER

There SHOULD BE NO WHITESPACE AFTER link_to if there is also a paren:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("subdirectory/image.png"), image_path("subdirectory/image_full.png", image)) %>
```

Comment: What are the error messages you get?

Comment: syntax errors that don't mean anything to me just yet. expecting keyword_end, expecting ')'.  The parens are balanced though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= link_to image_path("subdirectory/image_full.png") do %>
  <%= image_tag "subdirectory/image.png" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yeah, i've been seeing this way around a bit.  i think the do end is more for readability, though than anything else?  it also makes more explicit the space vs paren issue i had

Answer (score 2):

Try `image_path` instead of `asset_path` like so:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("subdirectory/image.png"), image_path("subdirectory/image_full.png")) %>
```

Comment: That's not working either.  I've even made both images the same as the the first that I can confirm is a correct path.  I keep on getting sytax error for the comma, expecting only image_tag to be a part of the link_to???

Comment: Woops, I missed that too. Easy mistake to make. Fixed in my answer now.