# How to give image as href in link_to in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My code is

```
<%= link_to image_tag("user.png", class: "profile-img"), "/images/user.png", class: "colorbox" %>
```

If I give

```
<%= link_to image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:thumb), class: "profile-img"),current_user.avatar.url, class: "colorbox" %>
```

It works fine but in previous case it cant't find user.png.

I want to give href of link to a static image

Comment: where is the image in your file structure?

Comment: image in assets/images/user.png

Comment: You are using paperclip is that right?
Question: Why would you use a static link if you have paperclip included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to image_tag("user.png", class: "profile-img"), image_path("user.png"), class: "colorbox" %>
```

Good answer: [Rails 4 link_to larger, static image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989816/rails-4-link-to-larger-static-image)

---

The `image_tag` helper will use [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) to find the image to display.

As such, you may benefit from either using `asset_path("user.png")` or `image_path("user.png")` in the link.

The added benefit of this is that it will change depending on your environment (`production` vs `development`). IE in production, it will look for your precompiled assets first.

Comment: asset_path("user.png") works :).
Can you tell me the difference b/w asset_path and image_path?
Thanks

Comment: I think `image_path` just looks in the `/images` directory, whilst `asset_path` looks in all. I'm not actually sure to be honest!